# Determinant of a Linear Transformation 2

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the determinant of the linear transformation $$T(M) = \begin{bmatrix}
>     2       & 3    \\
>     0       & 4 
> \end{bmatrix}M$$ from the space $V$ of upper triangular $2 \times2$ matrices to $V$.

The solution given is $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
    2       & 0&0   \\
    0       & 2&3  \\ 0&0&4
\end{bmatrix}$$ so $\det(T)=\det(A)=16 \ $  which I have no idea how it was produced? Why is $A$ a $3\times 3$ matrix, aren't we in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}                                                                                                                                                                                 
e_1                                                                                                                                                                                            
&=                                                                                                                                                                                             
\begin{bmatrix}                                                                                                                                                                                
1 & 0 \\                                                                                                                                                                                       
0 & 0                                                                                                                                                                                          
\end{bmatrix}                                                                                                                                                                                  
&                                                                                                                                                                                              
e_2                                                                                                                                                                                            
&=                                                                                                                                                                                             
\begin{bmatrix}                                                                                                                                                                                
0 & 1 \\                                                                                                                                                                                       
0 & 0                                                                                                                                                                                          
\end{bmatrix}                                                                                                                                                                                  
&                                                                                                                                                                                              
e_3                                                                                                                                                                                            
&=                                                                                                                                                                                             
\begin{bmatrix}                                                                                                                                                                                
0 & 0 \\                                                                                                                                                                                       
0 & 1                                                                                                                                                                                          
\end{bmatrix}                                                                                                                                                                                  
\end{align*}
forms a basis for $V$. Furthermore, note that
\begin{align*}                                                                                                                                                                                 
T(e_1) &= \color{red}{2}\,e_1+\color{red}0\,e_2+\color{red}0\,e_3 \\                                                                                                                                                              
T(e_2) &= \color{green}0\,e_1+\color{green}2\,e_2+\color{green}0\,e_3 \\                                                                                                                                                              
T(e_3) &= \color{blue}0\,e_1+\color{blue}3\,e_2+\color{blue}4\,e_3                                                                                                                                                                 
\end{align*}
This implies that the matrix of $T$ relative to the basis
$\beta=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is
$$
[T]_\beta=
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}2 & \color{green}0 & \color{blue}0 \\
\color{red}0 & \color{green}2 & \color{blue}3 \\
\color{red}0 & \color{green}0 & \color{blue}4
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Alternatively, note that 
\begin{align*}
v_1 &=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
&
v_2 &=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
&
v_3 &=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 3/2 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
is a basis for $V$ consisting of eigenvectors for $T$. Furthermore, the eigenvalue corresponding to $v_1$ and $v_2$ is $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=2$ while the eigenvalue corresponding to $v_3$ is $\lambda_3=4$. This implies that 
$$
\det T=\lambda_1\cdot\lambda_2\cdot\lambda_3=2\cdot 2\cdot 4=16
$$

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thank you!